# MovieClip inside scrollPane AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I loaded a movieClip into a scrollpane from my library and in that movieclip there is a text field. How do I dynamically insert text into that text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to do it.
The first one is if you still got a reference to that MovieClip then you can just type

```
myMovieClip.myTextField.text = "foo";
```

If you don't have any reference you can do like this

```
myScrollPane.source.myTextField.text = "foo";
```

In your case myScrollPane.source should have a reference to your MovieClip

Comment: i get ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property txt not found on String and there is no default value.
 at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Comment: He answered correctly, and the information you just posted seems to suggest that you typed "txt" instead of "text". Please accept his answer.

Comment: txt is my textfield instance name

Comment: Can you post the line where you are trying to change text?

Comment: panE.source.txt.text = "foo";

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code. What the error is telling is that you are trying to access a property txt in a String varaible and String does not have a txt property. So either you are getting the error somewhere else in your code or panE.source is a String. And something i just thought right now; how do "load" the movieClip in to the scrollpane?

Comment: i am using the component parameters to input the movieclip.

Comment: I figured it out i added variable of the movieclip and it worked.... Thanks guys...